# Hosting CodeIgniter blog on Media Temple service

Tags: web-hosting, codeigniter, mediatemple

I am completely clueless about it and Media Temple's customer care doesn't provide any technical help. Here are my doubts:

1. Where should I upload my codeigniter blog files `/domain/myblog.com/html/` or `/domain/myblog.com/` ?
2. In config.php, I have updated base url from `http://localhost/myblog` to `http://myblog.com/`. Is it correct.
3. I have created a new mysql DB in Media Temple and updated database.php with the same.
4. There is a `.htaccess` file at `/domain/myblog.com/`. I have my own project specific `.htaccess` file. Should I replace/merge/leave it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Upload your CodeIgniter files to `/domain/myblog.com/html/`
2. Double check whether CodeIgniter needs that trailing slash or not.
3. Great.
4. Remove the original `.htaccess` in /domain/myblog.com/html/ and replace it with the one from CodeIgniter; don't merge.

All this said, the best advice I can give you is to move away from MediaTemple. Their hosting is setup in such a way that the web servers and database servers are in physically different locations, resulting in queries taking *way* longer than they should. Database-intensive applications hosted on MT are usually borderline unusable, and all MT's support will do is try to upsell you MySQL (& other) GridContainers.

Answer (score 0):

1) The files need to be uploaded to /domain/myblog.com/html/

2) The trailing slash can be used. It will not make a difference.

3) Perfect!

4) Delete the original .htaccess file and use the one provided by Codeigniter. Do not forget to check the .htaccess file for the settings.

As already mentioned by Yuriy Babenko, It is always better to use a hosting service that have web server and database server present at a common physical location.